ERROR ~ No such variable: still struggling with nextflow's channels behavior
I have been using Nextflow for quite some time now, but today I am stuck with this error and I cannot really figure out why it is happening.
I have this simple process that takes 3 input channel:
process anEasyOne {
    container 'legacy:latest'

    input:
        path "groupA/*"
        path "groupB/*"
        path groups_summary

    output:
        path("groups_metrics.tsv")

    """
    compute_metrics.py --a_group groupA --b_group groupB --stats ${groups_summary}
    """
}

A workflow eventually calls this process:
workflow {
    take: a_files
    take: b_files
    take: summary

    main:
        // other independent steps

        anEasyOne(a_files.collect(), b_files.collect(), summary)

        // ... rest of the workflow

}

This workflow is part of a larger project, and it is called as a sub-workflow, but nothing starts: nextflow throws the title error - No such variable: groups_summary - at the very beginning of the computation, right after parsing all script files but before a single process starts running.
This is an extract of the log:
Jun-25 15:36:26.823 [main] DEBUG nextflow.script.ScriptRunner - Parsed script files:
  Script_ed5649e41a62753a: /home/faabiioo/repos/nw/./modules/groups/main.nf
  Script_72aa75353630da24: /home/faabiioo/repos/nw/./modules/singles/main.nf
...
Jun-25 15:36:26.824 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Session aborted -- Cause: Unknown variable 'groups_summary'
Jun-25 15:36:26.856 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - The following nodes are still active:
...
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Unknown variable 'groups_summary'
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
...

Here is some runtime information:
Version: 23.10.1 build 5891
Created: 12-01-2024 22:01 UTC (23:01 CEST)
System: Linux 6.5.0-35-generic
Runtime: Groovy 3.0.19 on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 19.0.2+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu322.04
Encoding: UTF-8 (UTF-8)
Process: 153318@faabiioo-vm [127.0.1.1]
CPUs: 16 - Mem: 62.9 GB (52.1 GB) - Swap: 2 GB (2 GB)

I have been searching the documentation, and through github issues, and I am quite sure it must be related to channel semantic, but I can't really figure out what is the error I am making here.
Any help would be appreciated

Where are you creating the summary input channels? Can you add that code?

the summary channel is simply the output from a process elsewhere in the project, whose output is defined as output: path("summary.tsv"), emit: summary. I use the emit because that process has 2 outputs, and I need to use them in to different ways. Double-checked that the correct one is passed to this workflow

Have you tried using view to inspect summary? The errors all indicate either assigning the variable or that the channel is empty. Though I'm pretty sure the latter would be a different error.
Also, have you ensured the summary channel is a value channel and not a queue channel. Probably not really a problem if you're using DSL2, but old habits for me.

I did: the channel is not empty, and I am using DSL2 so the channel type shouldn't be a problem, at least not related to this error. Weird thing is: the same error occurred again, with a different variable, but apparently specifying the script: keyword before the actual process script block solves the problem! But I'm not sure this can be intended as a solution, because many other processes do not have that keyword explicitly set, and nothing fails. kind of frightening

How odd. I wonder that nextflow was trying to parse the block as if not the process script. But good you've found a solution.

you need use the keyword take: just once before all the inputs to the workflow. That may not solve your problem but at least would make your code more sound.

Also before the script's """ add script:; same, might not fix your problem but it might.

@Faabiioo sorry didn't read your script: comment before I posted mine.... I think that you should be happy if it fixes your problem.... is due to how Nextflow is using Groovy's DSL mechanism... adding the keyword there may make it do thing like initializing the state of the process  so it is important. Perhaps those other processes work because they seem to work rather than work or they are even simpler than yours and they can do with a half initialized state. Botton line is that based on documentation you need to add script (or shell or native), just do it.
